# Cuda C++ kernel using nested method calls of different objects

Tags: c++, object, methods, cuda

I'm currently working on a program that performs multiple parallel and independent calculations that I decided to implement with Cuda. In detail I want to call a Kernel from inside a method of a class what seems to work. The kernel gets the object from which it is called in its current state using the "this"-pointer being copied to device memory.

It is important to know that this object contains a vector of objects from another class that has been assigned beforehand in the host code. Inside the kernel I want to call a method on every object inside the vector which has already been declared as **device** code. And this somewhat nested call of methods does not work because, instead of a valid result vector, I get back a vector of zeros which indicates that something does not work properly although everything should be compatible with Cuda so far.

There are two classes:

```
//Header of Ding-class
#pragma once
#include<cuda.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#include<cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "test_klasse.cuh"

class Ding
{
private:
    int index;
    size_t size;
    double* result_vector;
    double prop;
    double result;
    test_klasse* stuff_vector;

public:
    __host__ __device__ Ding(int, size_t);
    __host__ __device__ ~Ding();

    __host__ void calculate_stuff(double);
    __host__ __device__ double get_prop();
    __host__ __device__ double get_result();
    __host__ __device__ double get_value(int);
};

//Source code of Ding-class
#include "Ding.cuh"

__global__ void calculation(Ding* teil, double* result, int size, double coeff) {

    int ii = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (ii < size){
        result[ii] = (*teil).get_value(ii);
    }
}

__host__ __device__ Ding::Ding(int ind, size_t vec_size) {
    index = ind;
    prop = 1;
    result = 0;
    size = vec_size;

    stuff_vector = (test_klasse*)malloc(size * sizeof(test_klasse));

    result_vector = (double*)malloc(size * sizeof(double));

    for (int ii = 0; ii < size; ii++) {
        result_vector[ii] = 0;
        stuff_vector[ii] = test_klasse::test_klasse(ii, 2 * ii);
    }
}

__host__ __device__ Ding::~Ding() {};

__host__ void Ding::calculate_stuff(double coeff) {
    prop = 1;
    double* d_result;
    int* d_size;
    double sum = 0;
    Ding* d_teil;

    cudaMalloc(&d_teil, sizeof(Ding));
    cudaMalloc(&d_result, size * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc(&d_size, sizeof(int));

    cudaMemcpy(d_size, &size, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_teil, this, sizeof(Ding), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    calculation <<< size / 512 + 1, 512 >>> (d_teil, d_result, size, coeff);

    cudaMemcpy(result_vector, d_result, size * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int ii = 0; ii < size; ii++) {
        std::cout << result_vector[ii] << std::endl;
        result += result_vector[ii];
    }
}

__host__ __device__ double Ding::get_prop() {
    return prop;
}

__host__ __device__ double Ding::get_result() {
    return result;
}

__host__ __device__ double Ding::get_value(int index) {
    return stuff_vector[index].get_sum();
}
```

The "inner" class the objects inside the vector "stuff_vector" belong to is defined as follows:

```
//Header of test_klasse
#pragma once
#include<cuda.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#include<cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

class test_klasse
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    __host__ __device__ test_klasse(int, int);
    __host__ __device__ ~test_klasse();
    __host__ __device__ void add(int);
    __host__ __device__ int get_sum();
};

//Source code of test_klasse
#include "test_klasse.cuh"

__host__ __device__ test_klasse::test_klasse(int input_a, int input_b) {
    a = input_a;
    b = input_b;
}

__host__ __device__ test_klasse::~test_klasse() {}

__host__ __device__ void test_klasse::add(int s) {
    a += s;
    b -= s;
}

__host__ __device__ int test_klasse::get_sum() {
    return a + b;
}
```

Finally the main function just creates an object of the Ding-class and performs the calculations that again invoke the kernel:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include "Ding.cuh"
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    Ding teil(5, 50);
    //std::cout << "Old result: " << std::endl;
    teil.calculate_stuff(3.1234);
    std::cout << "New result: " << teil.get_result() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Everything compiles without an error and as long as I just call a method of the Ding-object to assign it to results I get a reasonable results. Things start to fail when I call methods on the members of the "stuff_vector".

Does anybody know what's going wrong or which limitations of the Cuda computation I am currently not aware of?

Comment: `malloc` run on the device allocates memory on a runtime heap that is not accessible via the standard host side `cudaMemcpy` API. I'm pretty sure if you do some error checking you will see some invalid parameter errors at a minimum

Answer (score 1):

`cudaMemcpy(d_teil, this, sizeof(Ding), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)` will only perform a shallow copy of the instance of `Ding`.
That is,`this->stuff_vector` and `d_teil->stuff_vector` will have the same pointer value.

However, since `this->stuff_vector` points to host-memory, `d_teil->stuff_vector` will point to the same host-memory as well. Thus it must not be dereferenced in device code.

There are also potential issues in your code which are not related to CUDA. For example, you assign an object of a class to uninitialized memory, which can cause errors for non-trivial assignment operators.

```
    stuff_vector = (test_klasse*)malloc(size * sizeof(test_klasse));

    for (int ii = 0; ii < size; ii++) {
        stuff_vector[ii] = test_klasse::test_klasse(ii, 2 * ii);
    }
```